# what's wrong in this heapifying algorithm

Tags: data-structures

i'm not sure what wrong with my code and its not converting the array into heap.please help!!!
pointer a is the pointer to the array passing to the function(you must have figured out that by now) and z is the length of the array.
please do explain me why i'm wrong.
i'm noob at coding(you must have figured out that also by my code for sure).
thank you for your precious time.

```
int heapy(int *a,int z)
{
 for(i = 0; i<z ;i++)
 {   c[i] = a[i];
    for(j = i; j >= 0; --j)
    {   y = (j-1)/2;
        if(c[j] > c[y])
        {   temp = c[y];
            c[y] = c[j];
            c[j] = temp;
            j = y;}
        else
         break;

           }
         }
       }
```

Comment: Please include example input, correct output for the example and the output of your program

Comment: {input as 5,7,6,9,8} {output: 79658}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point: You don't need the loop over j and that is where you have your problem. That is true, that you should assign y value to j, but just after that you decrement j in loop, so finally you get y - 1.
What you should do is either just change line `j = y;` to `j = y + 1`, or change the loop to

```
y = (j - 1) / 2
while (c[j] > c[y]){

   temp = c[y];
   c[y] = c[j];
   c[j] = temp;
   j = y;
   y = (j - 1) / 2;
}
```

Second point: please do not compress your code like this. New line after bracket is much more readable.

EDIT:
Full implementation in C++ looks like this:

```
int heapy(int *a, int *c, int z)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++){
        c[i] = a[i];
        int j = i;
        int y = (j - 1) / 2;
        while(c[j] > c[y]){
            int temp = c[y];
            c[y] = c[j];
            c[j] = temp;
            j = y;
            y = (j - 1) / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

If array of i elements is a heap than you should add element on its end and swap it with it's parents as long as they are less than it.

Comment: not working. i'm trying to to convert into max heap but when giving input as 57698, output is 59678.

Comment: It produces 9, 8, 6, 5, 7 for your input.

Answer (score 0):

In short: your program is too long by three characters: just remove `--j` from it.